PowerShell convert Int to Hex and write info to text file
I'm working on PowerShell Module Library that we want to use in our environment to simplify some coding.
I'm having small module that read registry values, and I want to do the following
Module reads DWORD value, but it should show not only Decimal but also Hex value
Log "Operating System UBR: $(GetDWORDValue "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "UBR" "64")"

Log "Operating System UBR (hex): ($(GetDWORDValue "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "UBR" "64")).ToString('X')"

Output
[06/21/2024 14:15:34 - TemplateScript.ps1] Operating System UBR: 3737
[06/21/2024 14:15:34 - TemplateScript.ps1] Operating System UBR (hex): (3737).ToString('X')
item in Bold is not correct and should show 'E99'
I've tried various combinations:

Tried with separate variable which works is overkill in my opinion
using the {0} -f $ubrvalue.ToString('X')  does not work either when using the log module it does work if I create separate variable, and when trying from console I'm able to make it work also just not when trying to use the Log functionality.

Which is basically module that's using Add-Content and as param the text that I'm passing.
Log module
function Log {
    param (
        [string]$sText
    )

    $logFolderPath = "C:\Logs"
    if ($sAppName -eq $null) {
          $sAppName = $scriptName
        }
    $logFilePath = Join-Path -Path $logFolderPath -ChildPath "$sAppName.log"

    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $logFolderPath)) {
        New-Item -Path $logFolderPath -ItemType Directory
    }

    $sCurTime = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    $logEntry = "[$sCurTime - $scriptName] $sText"

    Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value $logEntry
}

Any idea/suggestions are welcome
Thx!

You need to surround the whole (...).ToString('X') invocation in a subexpression $(...):
Log "Operating System UBR (hex): $((GetDWORDValue "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "UBR" "64").ToString('X'))"

You can also use a single pipeline by having ForEach-Object invoke the ToString method, like so:
Log "Operating System UBR (hex): $(GetDWORDValue "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "UBR" "64" |ForEach-Object ToString 'X')"

Makes it slightly more readable without the double parens :)

Thank You that did the trick, appreciated!!!!!

To complement Mathias' helpful answer; you might also use the Format operator -f for this:
Log ('Operating System UBR (hex): {0:X}' -f (GetDWORDValue "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "UBR" "64"))

